# Cannot convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tryinging to get a list of all my categories in my view but it is not working out that great for me. 
This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    ViewBag.Operation = id;
    ViewBag.Products = _db.Products.ToList();
    ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(_db.Categories, "Id", "Name");
    Product product = _db.Products.Find(id);
    return View(product);
}
```

And this is the code I try to run in my view

```
var categories = ((List<string>) ViewBag.CategoryId);
```

But I do get this following error:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Comment: So it says that Cannot convert type SelectList to List

Comment: Why do you want to run that code in your view? It is not a `List<string>`, so you cannot cast to it.

Comment: @CodeCaster Because I am going to make tabs, so i need to get each categoryname and sort out each item under right category

Comment: So don't use a SelectList then.

Comment: Indeed - you need to make up your mind whether you want a `SelectList` or a `List<string>`. They're different things, so any one thing can't be both.

Comment: @JonSkeet I did create, add / edit my items in that same view as well there for I did assume I had to use SelectList.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow that comment at all. Do you understand that `SelectList` and `List<string>` are different? Do you understand why it's not working?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, and I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to cast it to `SelectList` in View, as in controller action you are creating object of type `SelectList` not `List<string>` :

```
var categories = ViewBag.CategoryId as SelectList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why `SelectList`? You can simply use List in your action method:

```
ViewBag.Categories = _db.Categories.ToList();
```

Comment: Because I have Create in the same view, and Create Action had SelectList so I did assume I had to have it in there aswell.